# Must the intersection of a certain decreasing sequence of open sets be non-empty

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to show the open mapping theorem. As I was trying to prove it, I made the following conjecture:

> Let $X$ be a complete metric space. Let $V_1,V_2,...$ be a sequence of
>   open sets in $X$ such that: $$V_1\supseteq \overline{V_2}\supseteq
>  V_2\supseteq \overline{V_3}\supseteq V_3\supseteq
>  \overline{V_4}\supseteq V_4\supseteq .... $$Then
>   $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}V_n\not=\emptyset$

**Question 1:** Is the above conjecture true ?

I would be able to prove the open mapping theorem if the conjecture is true, but I am curious about this question as well:

**Question 2:** Does the conjecture hold even if we don't require $X$ to be complete ?

Thank you

---

**Edit:** Neal answered both questions. There is still one more question that Ii formulated after seeing the counterexamples of Neal.

**Question 3:** Does the conjecture hold if $X$ is a complete bounded metric space ?

Comment: Is $\overline{V}$ the closure of $V$?

Comment: @LordSoth Yes. ${}$

Comment: You have a nonempty intersection also if the diameters of the $V_i$ shrink to $0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't get your comment. It seems to me that the $V_i$ in yor comment are open balls. No ? Could you rephrase your comment please ?

Comment: But you have the additional premise that $V_i \supset \overline{V}_{i+1} \supset V_{i+1}$, so the intersection of the $V_i$ is the intersection of the $\overline{V}_i$. Now, if the diameters shrink to $0$, the intersection is nonempty. Take $x_i \in V_i$; that is a Cauchy sequence. Its limit is contained in the intersection.

Comment: @DanielFischer OK I agree that $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} V_n=\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} \overline{V_n}$, but I still don't understand the second part. What do you mean by the diamater of an open set, how is it defined ? I am reading your edited comment now

Comment: $\operatorname{diam}(A) = \sup \{ d(x,y) : x,y \in A\}$, the supremum of the distances between points of a set.

Comment: @DanielFischer I suppose by diameter of V you mean the supremum of the set of distances between elements of V, and this supremum must be defined because the space is bounded. OK now I understand your argument. Any idea about the case when the diameters dont shrink to zero

Comment: @DanielFischer Good point !

Comment: If the space is not bounded, a diameter may be infinite. However, if the diameters shrink to $0$, from some point on, the sets have finite diameter. If the diameters don't shrink to $0$, the only general condition that comes to mind is that one of the $\overline{V}_i$ is compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the conjecture need not be true. Consider $V_i = (i,\infty)\subset\mathbb{R}$. Then:
$$(1,\infty)\supseteq [2,\infty)\supseteq (3,\infty)\supseteq \cdots$$
but (by the Archimedean principle) their intersection is empty.

If $X$ is bounded but not complete, the conjecture still does not hold: Consider the punctured interval $X = [-1,0)\cup(0,1]$ and a $$V_i = \bigg(-\frac{1}{i},\frac{1}{i}\bigg)\cap X.$$

---

If $X$ is just bounded and complete, I think it won't work. We'll take a disjoint union of countably many little balls and then let $V_i$ be the union of all but finitely many of them.

Consider a separable infinite-dimensional Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $e_i$. Define auxiliary sets 
$$E_{i,\epsilon} = B(e_i,\epsilon).$$ 
Choose $\epsilon$ small enough so that the $E_{i,\epsilon}$ are pairwise disjoint and put
$$V_i = \bigcup_{j=i}^\infty E_{j,\epsilon/i}$$
Now for each $i$, we've $\bar{V_i}\subseteq V_{i-1}$, and yet the intersection of all $V_i$ is empty.

Since $V_1$ is contained in the ball of radius $1 + \epsilon$, it is a subset of the bounded, closed metric space $\overline{B(0,1+\epsilon)}$.

This example may be easier to visualize if you consider the simpler space defined as a countably infinite collection of intervals $[0,1]$ wedged at $0$, i.e.,
$$\bigsqcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}} [0,1]_i/(\forall i,j\ \ 0_i\sim 0_j).$$

Let $E_{(j,\epsilon)} = (1-\epsilon, 1]_j$, the open $\epsilon$-neighborhood of the endpoint of the $j^{th}$ interval, and $V_i$ the union of all but the first $i$ of the $E_{j,\epsilon/i}$s. As $i$ increases, the size of each $E_j$ shrinks, so $\overline{V_{i+1}}\subseteq V_i$ for all $i$. But any $x\in V_1$ is only contained in finitely many $\overline{V_i}$, so the intersection is empty.

---

However, if $X$ is compact, you can get your result by arguing that
$$V_1\cap \bar{V_2}\cap V_3\cap\cdots = \bar{V_1}\cap\bar{V_2}\cap\bar{V_3}\cap\cdots.$$

Comment: +1 What about if $X$ is bounded and complete ? as the conjecture being true for bounded and complete spaces would still be useful for me. Thanks

Comment: If $X$ is compact, I think you can get it by arguing that the intersection you identify is equal to the intersection of the closures, which is nonempty as an intersection of compact sets. I'm not sure about closed and bounded.

Comment: Yes compact is not a problem. Proving the conjecture for bounded and complete metric spaces would still allow me to prove the open mapping theorem. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Amr I'll think about this. The first place I'd look for intuition or counterexamples is the open unit ball of an infinite-dimensional Banach space.

Comment: Dear Neal, It's 1:15 am in my country now. and I need to sleep. I saw that you edited your answer to answer question 3 negatively. I will certainly read your answer tomorrow morning. Thanks for your help and your time.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Question 1 : false .  take $X = \mathbb{R}$, $V_n = (-\infty, -n)$.