# Non-empty intersection of decreasing open sets

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(G_n)$ be a decreasing sequence of nonempty open sets in a complete metric space $X$, and let us assume that the diameter of $G_1$ is finite. Does it follow that $\bigcap_n G_n \neq \emptyset$?

My attempt: Replace each $G_n$ with a smaller open set $E_n\neq \emptyset $ such that $G_1=E_1$ and $E_{n+1} \subseteq \overline{E}_{n+1} \subseteq E_n$. Then 
$$
\emptyset\neq \bigcap_n\overline{E}_n= \bigcap_n E_n \subseteq \bigcap_n G_n.
$$
Is this possible / necessary?
(Related [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549505/must-the-intersection-of-a-certain-decreasing-sequence-of-open-sets-be-non-empty).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $G_n:=(0,1/n)$ in the complete metric space $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: GG. $\mbox{}{}$

Comment: Dear John, thanks for your quick answer. You are clearly right, we need at least the assumption $\overline{G}_{n+1}\subseteq G_n$ for all $n$.

Comment: @Nduccio Yeah I deleted that comment promptly :D I agree that we likely need compactness. I'll try to think of an example

Comment: @JohnGriffin I am a bit afraid to have asked, a posteriori, such a trivial question. But we learn by doing mistakes :D Thank you John

Comment: @Nduccio No problem! For your related question, let's consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete metric. This space is complete and the same $G_n$ are clopen, but fail to have nonempty intersection.

Comment: @JohnGriffin I agree, good job